# write() to sysfs entry /sys/bus/pci/devices/.../driver/remove_id fails

Tags: c, linux, pci, sysfs

Seeing the *write()* function failing on */sys/bus/pci/devices/.../driver/remove_id* file returning -1 with **errno** equal to 19 (**ENODEV**).

But, same works fine via command line. I have checked the file permission which seems to be fine (--w-------) for user to perform write on this file.

```
int fp = 0;
int buffer_length = 0;
int bytes_written = 0;

fp = open(cmd_buf, O_WRONLY); // where cmd_buf will hold this string 
                              // "/sys/bus/pci/devices/.../driver/remove_id"
if (fp == -1)
{
    return -1;
}

// where inbuf will be a char * pointing to pci vendor device id like 
// this, "XXXX YYYY"
bytes_written = write(fp, in_buf, sizeof(in_buf));
printf(" bytes_written : %d \n ", bytes_written);
```

Seeing bytes_written equal to -1 and **errno** shows 19.

Please let me know if you find something wrong with the code snippet?

Comment: You need a complete example, i.e. `in_buf`'s contents should be in your example, as well as `#include`-s, and the code should be inside `main`. Also you claim *same works fine via command line* - you have to write *exactly* what command line you issue that works. It should be trivial to convert it to C, but since you don't show what you're doing, it's impossible to tell. **This is an easy problem to solve once you provide all needed information**.

Comment: Sure, Thank you for suggestion. Per observation, the target file needs sudo privileges as it is owned by root & was trying with another user with sudo privileges'. Got around this problem by using system() function and passed in the command that needs execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not provide enough information to pinpoint the problem.

However, here is an example program, example.c, that shows that it is your implementation that has the bug:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Write string 'data' to existing file or device at 'path'.
   Returns 0 if success, errno error code otherwise.
*/
int write_file(const char *path, const char *data)
{
    const char *const  ends = (data) ? data + strlen(data) : data;
    ssize_t            n;
    int                fd;

    /* NULL or empty path is invalid. */
    if (!path || !*path)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_NOCTTY | O_CLOEXEC, 0666);
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno; /* errno already set by open(). */

    /* Write the contents of data. */
    while (data < ends) {
        n = write(fd, data, (size_t)(ends - data));
        if (n > 0) {
            /* Wrote n bytes. */
            data += n;
        } else
        if (n != -1) {
            /* C Library bug: Should never occur. */
            close(fd);
            return errno = EIO;
        } else {
            /* Error in errno. */
            const int  saved_errno = errno;
            close(fd);
            return errno = saved_errno;
        }
    }

    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        /* It is possible for close() to report a delayed I/O error. */
        return errno;
    }

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}

static void usage(const char *argv0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv0);
    fprintf(stderr, "       %s FILE CONTENTS\n", argv0);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "This does the same thing as 'echo -n \"CONTENTS\" > FILE'.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        usage((argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else
    if (argc > 3) {
        usage((argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        usage((argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (write_file(argv[1], argv[2])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile it using e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 example.c -o example`, and run using e.g. `./example /sys/bus/pci/devices/.../driver/remove_id "vendor_id device_id"`.
Run it without arguments, or with `-h` or `--help` as the only argument, and it will print usage information to standard error.

The program essentially does what `echo -n "vendor_id device_id" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/.../drivers/remove_id` does.

If it is successful, it will not output anything, just return success (exit status 0).  If there is any kind of an error, it will report it to standard error.

If you know the target path is always a device or a pseudo-file (like those in /sys or /proc), use `fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_CLOEXEC);` instead.  `O_CLOEXEC` means that if the process forks at any point, this particular file descriptor is not copied to the child process.  `O_NOCTTY` means that if the path is a tty device, and the current process does not have a controlling terminal, the kernel is NOT to make the opened device the controlling terminal.

`echo -n` uses `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`, so that if the target path exists and is a normal file, it is truncated, but if it does not exist, it is created.  It does not affect opening existing character devices and pseudofiles.  Whenever `O_CREAT` is used, there must be a third parameter, which affects the access mode of the file created.  This mode is usually `0666`, allowing read and write access as moderated by the current umask.  One can obtain the current umask using `mode_t mask = umask(0); umask(mask);`.  Access mode bits set in umask are always zero in the final access mode, and access mode bits clear in umask are taken from the third parameter of the open() command when the file is created.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Infact, this code of yours share revealed the actual root of the problem.

Comment: Seeing EACCES while opening the target file.
Using sudo, the shell command passes.
    echo "XXXX YYYY" > sudo /sys/bus/pci/devices/.../driver/remove_id passes

Comment: So, to get around this problem used system() function to run this.

But, it will be a great thing if there could be an explanation on how to deal with a file where you issue sudo & run this command at open() itself.

Comment: @Vijay: This is a matter of *privileges*.  Options vary from making the binary setuid root (in which case the binary will always run with superuser/root privileges, no matter who or what runs it), to moving this part to a separate helper binary (so that only that part is setuid root), to moving this part to a helper script, which uses `sudo another-helper-script`, which verifies the parameters and then does the echo; and sudo configuration that allows the latter script to be run as root (by admin users, for example).  There are other options also.

Comment: @Vijay: The "best" or recommended way to grant the necessary privileges really depends on what your program does, besides detach a driver from a PCI device.  Indeed, I would suggest you ask a new question, perhaps here or perhaps at unix.stackexchange.com, for suggestions as to how best deal with privileges (granting privileges) in your particular overall scenario.  Remember, to be able to detach a driver from a PCI device, you do need root privileges; but whether to isolate the privileges to that, or if other parts of your program also need root privileges, determines *how* you should do it.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks. So, here is the summary of my understanding. 1. Use a separate script to modify permissions via setuid. 2. Run sysfs command via open/write() -> which will work as per expectation. 3. Revert the UID on the target file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible problems:

1. Using *sizeof(in_buf)* in the *write()* system call writes the string "vendorId deviceId" and may be more garbage data behind it if *in_buf[]* is bigger than 10 chars.
2. Perhaps *in_buf* is not a table but a pointer and so, *sizeof(in_buf)* will return 4 or 8 (the size of the pointer respectively for 32 or 64 bits systems) but not the length of the string it points to.

So, in both cases (*in_buf* defined as a table or a pointer), *strlen(in_buf)* instead of *sizeof(in_buf)* is the most secured solution for the length of the data to write provided that the string is terminated by '\0'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment.

Comment: Actually before using sizeof(in_buf) operator, have tried strlen(in_buf) got the "vendor_id device_id" as 9. But while using sizeof(in_buf) shows 120, which is the list size 120 bytes per declaration. As part of checks, have checked the file permissions which seems to be ok as well. Wondering the errno showing up as ENODEV but sysfs entry seems to be valid.

Comment: So, the answer is No. It didnt solve the problem even after using strlen(in_buf). Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding '\n' at the end of the string ? Because when you do "echo "XXXX YYYY" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/.../driver/remove_id" introduces an '\n'.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It didn;t work either. Per observation, the target file needs sudo privileges as it is owned by root & was trying with another user with sudo privileges'.